# Почему factory в Angular не работает как предполагается?

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('events.services', [])
    .factory('EventService', function($http, $cordovaSQLite) {
        return {
            test: function() {
                return 'It Works!';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Контроллер**

```
.controller('NearCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cordovaSQLite, EventService) {
    var test = EventService.test;
    console.log(test); //вроде как должно вернуть It works, но возвращает function test();
})
```

Почему не возвращает значение? Что я делаю неправильно? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так `EventService.test();`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Может потому, что `test` - это функция и её стоит вызывать? =)

1:

```
EventService.test();
```

2:

```
test();
```

3:

```
return {
    test: function() {
        return 'It Works!';
    }()
}
```

Comment: Ну и да, как вы понимаете, 3й способ - просто для примера. Не надо так делать в данном случае, т.к. `test` будет выполняться каждый раз при инициализации модуля.